# Suddenly, many comboboxes are failing to fill

Tags: ms-access

A couple of weeks ago, our Access application suddenly began to fail mysteriously. Comboboxes on random forms would not fill with rows when recordsources were set. These include forms that have not changed in years. Stepping through the code in the debugger always results in a successful outcome. Trying multiple times consecutively would occasionally work. One or two computers still work reliably, though these have a source control addon called Ivercy installed. When you run the deployed version (without the addon active) these machines show the same unreliability.

Last week, we found more issues including some forms and reports that would not populate on initial opening. Reselecting the same filter date (or other rowsource changes) once the form is open brings up the expected set of rows. Again, loading the form while stepping through the code always works.

These behaviours lead me to believe there is some sort of fault that has been introduced in a recent Access update. Has anyone else seen this kind of problem?

One instance of this issue occurs on a very simple, one page report that has no user code in it at all. I would have been willing to believe that we had been doing something systematically wrong in our code, but this code-less report seems to suggest otherwise.

My machine (which exhibits the problem) is using Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise
Version 2105 (Build 14026.20308 Click-to-Run)

Comment: _suddenly began to fail mysteriously_. Computers just do what they are told. Something has changed. Do you have a backup of the file from before the date? How big is the file? Have you tried a compact and repair? Is the file on your local computer or on a file share

Comment: Nick, I keep telling people that. Nothing happens without a cause. The mystery here is that code that we have NOT changed is now not working. Even objects that have no code are suddenly not working. In this case, the cause is not changes we have deliberately made. I believe the "something" is internal to Access. I'm trying to find someone who has experienced this kind of issue to pin down what the change may be so we can find the fix.

Comment: To answer your comment further, we regularly compact before distributing. We even occasionally rebuild completely from text exports of the forms/reports/etc. The file does not appear to be corrupt, as evidenced by the fact that things always work when we step through the code line by line. There seems to be an internal timing issue (a race condition) that has been recently introduced into Access.

Comment: Very mysterious and frustrating! I can only suggest that you build a basic app from scratch and see if you can reproduce the issue and then raise a ticket with Microsoft. If you can't, it must be something in your app. Sorry I can't help further

Comment: So far unable to reproduce in a simple app. I assume it is something to do with the size/complexity of the original that causes the problem in the first place. I imagine MS does actually test on at least simple forms before distributing Access updates :) This app is 10 years old and continually changing. Several forms that are used constantly have failed at once without us changing any of our code. Very mysterious. :(